# How to validate merchant details in Amazon Payments?

Tags: amazon-pay, amazonsellercentral

We are using amazon payments as an payment option in our app, and I would like to inquire about one thing, whether it has any API calls or some methods to validate Merchant details so that we can validate the details for the Merchant whether they are valid or not. (i.e. Seller ID, Access key, Secret Key, Client ID)

Comment: Are you referring to Login and Pay with Amazon https://payments.amazon.com? If so, no API exists to get that information. Especially the secret key. The client Id is for Login with Amazon and the seller Id is used when integrating. The only information you can get from API is first name, email, and shipping address.

Comment: Can you describe your use case? From what you describe, it sounds like you're doing something unsupported, as no merchant should share their secret key.